# How do i pair my keyboard to my ipad?

Tags: keyboard

I have charged this keyboard for an hour and turned it on, and it still won't show up on the bluetooth to pair it to the iPad I’m using, when I turn the magic keyboard on the light lights up green then flashes blue then it stops, I don’t know what that means,

Also, I don’t know what the button above the power button is for. This keyboard doesn't have a place to change batteries cause it stuck on a fabric that the keyboard doesn't come off, so it's like a book.[image][image]

Comment: Exactly what kind of keyboard are we talking about? - The Magic keyboard only has a power slider on the back - there's no button above it? The Magic Keyboard has rechargable batteries that cannot be user-replaced.

Comment: I don’t know my friend gave it to me, it came with an old ipad, she’s not responding so i don’t know what to do, i will send a picture if i can of what it looks like.

Comment: A picture will be good!

Comment: That's not a Magic Keyboard at all. It's not an Apple product either. Can you find any logos or text on it describing who made it?

Comment: No, i got it from my friend and she dont know anything about it, i dont think

Comment: Take it out of the cover and look at the back...

Comment: I cant its like its glued

Comment: Then you have to guess. Try pressing the Bluetooth button once, twice, hold it for several seconds, etc. Some combination will probably put it in pairing mode.

Comment: Its a logitech keyboard, it wont pair, its wont even pair to my iphone, i think its broken

Answer (score 1):

The Magic Keyboard has rechargeable batteries that cannot be replaced by the user. If you're running low on batteries, plugin a lightning cable to recharge the batteries.

You pair it with the iPad by first turning it on (move the slider on the back from the off-position to the green on-position). Then on the iPad open `Settings > Bluetooth`. Ensure that Bluetooth is enabled, and wait for the Magic Keyboard to appear in the list of devices below. Tap it to pair.

If the keyboard does not pair, you might have it paired to another iPad or computer that is nearby. Ensure that you're a good distance from any such device before pairing - or turn those devices off before pairing with your iPad.

Comment: Umm i have tried everything to pair the keyboard to the ipad, but it is acting like its still searching for the keyboard, i have edit my message up top and added two photos to see if anyone can help me cause i am confused!!